# EndOfStreamException when inserting long blob value of 14MB

Tags: mysql, .net, database

I'm getting the following exception while trying to insert a record into MySQL containing a long blob field of 14MB in size:

```
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException (0x80004005): Fatal error encountered during command execution. ---> 
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException (0x80004005): Fatal error encountered attempting to read the resultset. ---> 
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException (0x80004005): Reading from the stream has failed. ---> 
System.IO.EndOfStreamException
```

I already tried most tips I found online. This is my configuration:

- MySQL Connector for .Net 6.7.5.
- target blob field is of type longblob
- max_allowed_packet is set to 100M (in Client section AND MySQL section of ini file)

I'm using MySQL in a remote scenario, so my connection string contains `UseCompression=True`. When I set `UseCompression=False` everything works fine (but slower).

So my conclusion for now would be: There must be a bug in either in MySQL's client library or in the MySQL engine itself. I think what happens under the hood is the following:

- Source data is written into a local buffer on the client, along with an int containing the data size
- Source data is compressed locally before sending it over the wire. However, the library doesn't update the blob field's size to the new (compressed) size (--> bug)
- The client library then transmits to the server and keeps reading from the buffer, which is now smaller than the size-int. So we run into an `EndOfStreamException`.

This assumption would explain the experienced symptoms.

I have posted a bug report with Oracle: http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=72494

Does anyone know what could cause this exception?

Comment: I saw the same behavior but with a 7MB value. Disabling compression made it work again.